# ubuntu 20.04 reboot hanging - clamping QRV from 1 to 2

Tags: networking, reboot, network-bridge

my system is ubuntu 20.04, I use it mainly for LXD and Juju development..

I noticed the system asking for a reboot so I obliged.. but it is not rebooting and instead when I hit [esc] to watch the log it just says this at the end

```
IPV6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
IPV6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
```

do I need to look at the LXD network bridge or ?  for now I just had to hard shut it off, but this is not ideal obviously